# Can I prepare the same spell multiple times?

Tags: spells, spellcasting, basic-fantasy-rpg

The Core Rules say nothing about this that I can find.
I seem to run into this situation a lot but I don't think I can really clarify: Can I prepare the same spell multiple times?

Comment: Just to clarify, you *are* asking about the [tag:basic-fantasy-rpg] system? Not just about "basic fantasy rpg systems"?

Comment: Yes. I am asking about the [basic-fantasy-rpg](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/basic-fantasy-rpg) system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The core rules indeed don't explain a lot, but you could refer to the game BFRPG is "cloning", Basic D&D, that says on page B15 :

*A spell caster may, however, memorize the same spell twice if he or she is of a high enough experience level to do so. If so, only one is "erased" when the spell is cast; the other remains and may be used later.*